# не работают домены

Tags: nginx

настроил nginx  все работало пол часа , а потом перестало..
Подскажите в чем проблема

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server ;
        server_name ~^(?<domain>\w+)\.ru$;
        location / {
            root   /var/www/$domain.ru/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/$domain.ru/public;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^((?<sub>\w+)\.)(?<domain>\w+)\.ru$;
        location / {
            root   /var/www/$domain.ru/subdomains/$sub/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/$domain.ru/subdomains/$sub/public;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: субдомены работают нормально, а вот домены совсем не работают

Comment: логи? ошибки? статус работы сервера?

Comment: @TotalPusher в nginx access  пишет только по суб доменам , в nginx error пишет только ошибки по суб доменам, в php-fpm (/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log) пишет все стандартно running , ready , set interval

Comment: Какая ошибка из логов? Что говорит `sudo nginx -t`?

Comment: @TotalPusher ошибки в скрипте на субдомене . а проверка конфигурации говорит ok

Comment: Причем тут скрипты? Речь о конфиге Nginx. Вообще ничего не понятно. Если не сложно, оформите свою мысль понятным способом.